# call two procedures in select query?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How to call *two procedures* in a select query

e.g.:

```
SELECT sp_get_input_xml (:in_request_oid,
                                    :in_contract_oid,
                                    :in_contract_type,
                                    :out_input_xml
                                   ),
       sp_get_output_xml (:in_request_oid,
                                     :in_contract_oid,
                                     :in_contract_type,
                                     :out_output_xml
                                    )
  FROM DUAL;
```

What's the correct way to call two procedures using select statement?

Comment: **WHAT** database and what version???

Answer (score 2):

Looks like oracle. You can't call PROCEDURES from a SQL query, you can only call FUNCTIONS. If these are functions, that is perfectly acceptable. If you are procedures you'll need to use a PL/SQL block to call them.